# Excel formula: Amount + 1 x 1.5 =

Tags: microsoft-excel

We would like to set up a 1 step calculation to work out pricing automatically
i.e - 9 + 1 x 1.5 = 15

The first number (9) changes with each item
Thank you

Comment: Place the 9 into A1. In B1, enter `=A1+1*1.5`.

Comment: You'll want to use parenthesis for your (A1+1) before multiplying by 1.5, otherwise the formula will evaluate the 1*1.5 before adding it to A1 and the product of the formula will be 10.5 instead of the intended 15.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where your '9' resides in the grid, you just need to refer it in the price formula.  E.g. if your '9' is in A1, and you want your price to show in A2.  In A1, just type:

> 9

and in the A2 formula bar, type:

> =(A1+1)*1.5